# Using bind(this) in React

Tags: reactjs

Can I use any of these options? Do they all work the same way? I'm using ES6.

```
onChange={this.makeChange.bind(this)}

onChange={() => this.makeChange()}

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.makeChange = this.makeChange.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use all three. Even though they behave the same, they have different performance implications.

Binding the function in the `constructor` is the best option performance-wise, because the function is only created *once* when the component is instantiated. While with the other solutions a new function is created *whenever the component (re-)renders*. This will cause child components to also re-render, because their props have changed.

You can read more about this in the official React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

---

Personally, I prefer the following syntax using class properties (this is only available if you're using TypeScript or a [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)):

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick.
  // Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

This option is also explained in the React docs.

Comment: You can also find some examples how to prevent the usage of bind in the [eslint-plugin-react repository](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) under **Protips**